# Create amount of arrays based off variable number in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I was wondering how you create a variable amount of arrays in python. So if the user entered "3" you would get 3 arrays create. Might be obvios but got stuck after this:

```
baseNumber = 0
    #how many rows needed
    board_height = []
    print "select a width"
    x = int(raw_input(">"))
    print "select a height"
    y = int(raw_input(">"))
    #goes through height provided and breaks it down
    while (baseNumber < x):
        baseNumber = baseNumber + 1
        board_height.append(baseNumber)
```

It is probably easy and I look dumb but thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by a 'variable amount of arrays'? Do you want an array of a certain length, or a certain number of arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd make an array of arrays, actually a list of lists:

```
number_of_lists = ...
empty_lists = [[] for i in xrange(number_of_lists)]
```

If you wanted a list of lists with something in them already, just specify the initial contents of each individual list within the inner brackets:

```
nonempty_lists = [['a', 'b', 'c'] for i in xrange(number_of_lists)]
```

which would create `number_of_lists` lists, each containing three elements, `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`.

Of course, the example code you posted in your question has very little to do with this, so I'm not sure if I'm really answering the question you meant to ask...

Comment: I'm sorry complete noob here, but could you explain what exactly "[] for i in xrange(number_of_arrays)" does?

Comment: It creates `[]` (an empty list) `for` each number `i` `in` the iterator `xrange(...)`, which counts out `number_of_lists` values. (Specifically, `xrange(n)` counts from 0 to n-1.)

Comment: +1, I was trying to append in a list comprehension and couldnt get it to append anything other than `None`